# monotony for conway chains

Tags: number-theory, big-numbers

Let X and Y be chains, m and n be natural numbers with 0 < m < n. Is it always
 true that

$$X \rightarrow m \rightarrow Y < X \rightarrow n \rightarrow Y$$

?

I need this to bound the following sequence :

First of all, $(a_n)$ is defined by

$$a_1 = 10\ ,\   a_{n+1} = 10 \uparrow ^{a_n} 10 \ for\ all \ n\ge1$$

I calculated the following bounds for $a_n$ :

$$ 10\rightarrow 10 \rightarrow (k-1) \rightarrow 2 < a_k < 10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow k \rightarrow 2$$

Are these bounds correct ?

The next step is to define

$$b_n = a_{10 \uparrow ^n 10}$$

The goal is to bound $b_{10 \uparrow \uparrow 10}$

To do this, I calculated

$$b_n = a_{10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow n} < 10\rightarrow 10 \rightarrow (10 \rightarrow 10\rightarrow n) \rightarrow 2 < 10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow (10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow n \rightarrow 3) \rightarrow 2 = 10\rightarrow 10\rightarrow (n+1) \rightarrow 3$$

But I am not sure if the second inequality is valid.

I continued

$$b_{10\uparrow \uparrow 10} < 10\rightarrow 10 \rightarrow [(10\rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 2)+1]\rightarrow 3 < 10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow (10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 3) \rightarrow 3 < 10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow (10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4) \rightarrow 3 = 10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 4$$

But again I am not sure if the inequalities are all valid. The result (if correct)
 would show the incredible magnitude of the number $10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 4$

Comment: What's a chain?

Comment: See conway chain notation at wikipedia

Comment: Wait a minute --- you not only want people to help you, you want them to do the work of tracking down the meanings of the terms and notations you use? Don't you reckon you might want to make it easier for people to answer your question by meeting them halfway?

Comment: OK, some simple rules : The chain with the only one number p has value p. The chain $p \rightarrow q$ has value $p^q$ and the chain $p \rightarrow q \rightarrow r$ has value $p \uparrow ^r q$

Comment: The most important rule : For any chain X , $X \rightarrow (p+1) \rightarrow (q+1) = X \rightarrow (X \rightarrow p \rightarrow (q+1)) \rightarrow q$

Comment: A chain starting with $2 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow ...$ has always value 4. So, the monotony does not hold in this special case. For any chains X and Y, $X \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow Y = X$